# How to use Codeigniter routes with UTF-8 like Arabic characters 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, arabic-support, farsi

I am trying to use Arabic/Persian/Farsi character in the URL as a slug in Codeigniter like so:

I created **MY_url_helper.php** helper file to add the Arabic characters as accepted characters in the url_title Codeigniter function

```
/**
 * Create URL Title that allows Arabic characters
 *
 * Takes a "title" string as input and creates a
 * human-friendly URL string with a "separator" string 
 * as the word separator.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the string
 * @param   string  the separator
 * @return  string
 */
function url_title($str, $separator = '-', $lowercase = FALSE) {
    if ($separator == 'dash') {
        $separator = '-';
    } else if ($separator == 'underscore') {
        $separator = '_';
    }
    $q_separator = preg_quote($separator);
    $trans = array(
        '&.+?;' => '',
        '[^[U+0621]-[U+064a]a-z0-9 _-]' => '',
        '\s+' => $separator,
        '(' . $q_separator . ')+' => $separator
    );
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    foreach ($trans as $key => $val) {
        $str = preg_replace("#" . $key . "#i", $val, $str);
    }
    if ($lowercase === TRUE) {
        $str = strtolower($str);
    }
    return trim($str, $separator);
}
```

Then I had to enable Arabic characters as permitted uri character in the **config.php** file:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';  
$config['permitted_uri_chars']  .= 'لإ-لآ-أ-لآ-ض-ص-ث-ق-ف-غ-ع-ه-خ-ح-ج-د-ط-ك-م-ن-ت-ا-ل-ب-ي-س-ش-ئ-ء-ؤ-ر-ل-ا-ى-ة-و-ز-ظ-إ';
```

I tested it like so

```
http://dev/ar/pages/index/مهمتنا
```

and everything work, what is missing is the routes.

Just as this works in english:

```
$route['^(en|ar)/mission'] = "pages/index/mission";
```

I would like for this to work in arabic:

```
$route['^(en|ar)/مهمتنا'] = "pages/index/مهمتنا";
```

This gives **404**

I tried emptying the permitted_uri_chars like so:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

I still got the same exact issue; the link without routes work fine and the one with the route gave me **404**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is as simple as this:

in the **routes.php** config file do the following:

```
$mission = urlencode('مهمتنا');
$route['^(en|ar)/'.$mission] = "pages/index/".$mission;
```

no need to change the **permitted_uri_chars** in the **config.php** config file.

if the error was with the **permitted_uri_chars** the output would have been **400** ***"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."*** not **404**
as you can see here at system/core/URI.php, on line 231:

```
if (!preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
{
    show_error('The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.', 400);
}
```

Comment: would you please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229130/codeigniter-all-arabic-routes-are-not-working

Comment: No need to change or config each line with your solution, you can simply add this line to the `.htaccess` file as follow:

`RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]`

Comment: Hi, may i know how to write routes if the arabic values is dynamic?
$route['^(en|ar)/getdetails/(:any)'] = "controller/getdetails/$1";

http://localhost/project/ar/getdetails/arabic_value is the url calling from browser!

Comment: @youv if you created the `MY_url_helper` as described in the question, then it should work

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it's working with me just add this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow! worked like a charm, thanks for the life-saving trick :)

Comment: I have tried this trick but haven't worked for me, may i know the possibilities of failing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the arabic characters, so that instead of using:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars']  .= 'لإ-لآ-أ-لآ-ض-ص-ث-ق-ف-غ-ع-ه-خ-ح-ج-د-ط-ك-م-ن-ت-ا-ل-ب-ي-س-ش-ئ-ء-ؤ-ر-ل-ا-ى-ة-و-ز-ظ-إ';
```

You might want to use:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] .= '%D9%84%D8%A5-%D9%84%D8%A2-%D8%A3-%D9%84%D8%A2-%D8%B6-%D8%B5-%D8%AB-%D9%82-%D9%81-%D8%BA-%D8%B9-%D9%87-%D8%AE-%D8%AD-%D8%AC-%D8%AF-%D8%B7-%D9%83-%D9%85-%D9%86-%D8%AA-%D8%A7-%D9%84-%D8%A8-%D9%8A-%D8%B3-%D8%B4-%D8%A6-%D8%A1-%D8%A4-%D8%B1-%D9%84-%D8%A7-%D9%89-%D8%A9-%D9%88-%D8%B2-%D8%B8-%D8%A5';
```

Also you might want to remove the "-" character from the config item so the "permitted_uri_chars" config item would like:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] .= '%D8%A2%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%BE%D8%AA%D8%AB%D8%AC%DA%86%D8%AD%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%B0%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B3%D8%B4%D8%B5%D8%B6%D8%B7%D8%B8%D8%B9%D8%BA%D9%81%D9%82%DA%A9%DA%AF%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%8A%DB%B1%DB%B2%DB%B3%DB%B4%DB%B5%DB%B6%DB%B7%DB%B8%DB%B9%DB%B0';
```

This should solve your issue as those characters are being handled in the encoded form instead of their original values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my issue is with the routes not with the permitted_uri_chars, i tested it by leaving the $config['permitted_uri_chars']  = ''; empty

Answer (score -1):

use this->

```
urldecode(auto_link($url))
```