# Arabic language as get parameter not working in routes

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, arabic

Working on a codeigniter project, given routes for both english arabic languages. English parameter is working good arabic  value  cannot be accessed from controller

i have tried this solution in htaccess file rewrite rule by refering to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229130/codeigniter-all-arabic-routes-are-not-working) but not working

```
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

```
$route['^(en|ar)/CarDetails'] = "Car/CarDetails";

English URL:

http://localhost/project/en/CarDetails/car-code

Arabic URL:

http://localhost/project/ar/CarDetails/رمز السيارة
```

Car Code is a unique code for each car fetched from DB.

I need to fetch this car code in Arabic language as get parameter from browser in my controller so that i can fetch car details based on this code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following once, sorry I couldn't test it, should work IMHO though.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/ar/CarDetails/(.*)/?$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```